# Hyperlinks affecting how validation is added

Tags: excel, vba

I noticed that if I add hyperlinks to table column before validation list on another column it will affect how validation list is added.

For example:

```
RangeTarget(c, r).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=RangeTarget(c, r), Address:=hyperlink, TextToDisplay:="Link"
```

And another:

```
RangeTarget(c, r).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=celldata
```

If I don't add hyperlinks, celldata can be separated by ',' and if I add hyperlinks celldata can be separated with ';' being my local separator for excel.
Can someone retry this and confirm please.

The actual code is this:

```
RngTarget(2 + i, mvaln).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=RngTarget(2 + i, mvaln), Address:=rsrows(j, i), TextToDisplay:="Link"
RngTarget(2 + i, mvaln).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=rsrows(j, i)
```

I assume it affects RngTarget range, if I use it for both. I assume if I redefined RngTarget inbetween I could then separate items with ','. So I guess there is some hidden locale for range that is being changed after adding hyperlink.

EDIT:
Ok I reduced the problem to this.
If I add .ClearHyperlinks on `RngTarget(2 + i, mvaln)` before adding validation list, it will apparently separate list by "," character instead of ";".

Answer (score 0):

So basically if someone knows if this is a bug...

I run this on a table (after selecting 2 columns):

```
Sub test()
    Selection.ClearHyperlinks
    Selection.Validation.Delete
    Selection.Columns(2).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="a, b, c, d, e"
End Sub
Sub test2()
    Selection.ClearHyperlinks
    Selection.Validation.Delete
    Selection.Columns(1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Columns(1), Address:="no address", TextToDisplay:="Link"
    Selection.Columns(2).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="a, b, c, d, e"
End Sub
```

Test1 will list dropdown items correctly while test2 will not. For test2 I'd have to use ";" delimiter.
[image]

Adding hyperlinks to the column after adding the validation doesn't affect this. Also this is bugged not just on tables but also on range.